# Simplify this function with two modular arithmetic moduli

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to create a function with integer input $n \in \{0,1,2...8\}$. It first performs $(4+n)\,\mathrm{mod} \,9$, and let's call that $x \equiv (4+n)\, \mathrm{mod}\,9$. I want the output of the function to return $0$ if $x \in \{ 0,1,2\}$, returns 1 if $x \in \{ 3,4,5\}$, and returns 2 if $x \in \{ 6,7,8\}$. What function can accomplish this only using combinations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and perfectly dividing integers (like 10/2)? These can be used with different moduli and/or the set of all integers.

So the solution should map $(0,1,2,...8)$ to $(1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0,1)$.

Here's my solution, but I'm hoping for a better one, that doesn't rely on multiple moduli. $x$ belongs to $\{0,1,...8\}$, so apply integer division by 3 to get the desired output. This could be done with basic operations using $y \equiv x - \left(x\,\mathrm{mod} 3 \right)$, which is either $0$ or $3$ or $6$. Then dividing by 3 over the normal integers gives $0$ or $1$ or $2$, which is what we want.

But this solution is not ideal since it relies on multiple moduli as well as converting back to all integers at the end.

So I'm looking for either 1) a way to algebraically or conceptually simplify the function I proposed, $f(n)$, or 2) a completely different approach that is even better.

For context, I have matrices with entries between 0 and 8, and I want to perform various operations with them, while sticking to whole numbers.

Comment: What does "cannot be a finite field" have to do with computing $\lfloor x/3\rfloor$ without  using "rounding, integer division, or flooring"? Note that "without using" needs *precise* definition (e.g. you are implicitly using those operations when you use $\!\bmod\!\!)$. Lacking any such precise definition the question is not well-defined. Please explain the bigger picture, i.e. give some context explaining why you seek such an unnatural method.

Comment: Indeed, given that you have a restricted set of allowed operations in mind, I think the question would be clearer if you stated which operations are allowed (instead of some that are disallowed).

Comment: Okay, I added the restriction of moduli arithmetic operations only, with different moduli allowed. I removed the remark about finite fields, which is not central to the question.

Comment: Just to be certain, you're looking for a function that maps $n = (0,1 \dots 8) \mapsto (1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0,0,0,1)$. Is that correct?

Comment: (If that is correct, then I believe $\frac13 (n+4 - ((n+1) \bmod 3))$ suffices.)

Comment: I added the desired mapping for clarity. Your function looks right for 0 to 4, but for $n=5,6,7$ it appears to give 3, and for $n=8$ it gives $4$. So it would work in all cases if mod 3 is applied to the whole function afterwards.